# BLE Server side implementations using C++ in a Linux environment

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

Are there any samples of a **BLE Server implemented in C++ in a Linux environment**?
For context I have an **NVIDIA Jetson TX2 board** running **Ubuntu** and I'd like to have a BLE server in it that I can pair Android and iOS devices. The device will be broadcasting characteristics that the mobile app can subscribe to, and they can also send/receive messages preferably in **JSON** format. It currently has some Bluetooth codes but I think this only works in **Classic** mode:

```
...
int s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = *BDADDR_ANY_INITIALIZER;
loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 22;

int b = bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));
...
```

I am still very new to C++, Linux and BLE development in general, so I'd like to get pointers to the right direction.

Comment: Please check out https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt. You will need a dbus client to use the API.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is that you take the following direction:-

1. Implement your application through the command line.
2. Implement your application through an automated shell script.
3. (Optional) Implement your application using C/C++.

If having the application written in C/C++ is not a requirement, then I recommend skipping this step as you can achieve the same result with the shell script.

As for implementing the application through the command line, I recommend using bluetoothctl tool as can be seen in the following answer:-

- [BlueZ: How to set up a GATT server from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427768/bluez-how-to-set-up-a-gatt-server-from-the-command-line)

Once this starts working for you and you are able to connect from a remote device and browse the GATT table, convert the list of commands into a shell script and fire it to see the same results.

Finally, if this works for you up to this point, then the next step is to convert that shell script into a C/C++ application. You can do so by browsing the source code for the bluetoothctl command that was used earlier. You can find the source for the BlueZ stack [here](https://github.com/Vudentz/BlueZ), and the code for the bluetoothctl command can be found [here](https://github.com/Vudentz/BlueZ/blob/master/client/main.c).

I hope this helps.