# update local gatt characteristic value using bluetoothctl

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez, gatt

I have set up a gatt Server on an raspberry pi using bluetoothctl and BlueZ 5.50 (according to this thread: [BlueZ: How to set up a GATT server from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427768/bluez-how-to-set-up-a-gatt-server-from-the-command-line/52982329#52982329))
I can connect to the gatt server from an other machine and also read the given value. Now I want to try notify.

The subscription works fine, but how do I update the value on the local gatt server? I can't use select-attribute because my local services an characteristics do not show up in the list that appears when using autocomplete.

Would be nice if someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**view the server DB**

list-attributes local

**select the attribute before performing opertaion on that charecteristic**

select-attribute local

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same prob and i found solution for the same.
i am using bluez5.49. whenever notify was enabled in client, notify_io will be created and pipe will be established.
so if you write data in pipe fd, then it will be notified to client.