# How to modify the BLE gatt server profile

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I need to create a ble custom profile  for my peripheral server in Linux and C code.
I tried to modify existing time profile under /bluez_source_code/profiles/time folder.
I have modified

1. UUID number (added custom  UUID number in the uuid16_table in the UUID.h) and name
2. Added new characteristic

I have compiled the whole ble stack and tested the time profile.
The peripheral client sees the no change the UUID number and charateristic name.

Is there any any thing else I need to modify for the custom profile.

Comment: Keep in mind that a 16-Bit UUID is supposed to be assigned to a specific user/company/application by the Bluetooth SIG: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/ You should use a 128-Bit UUID for your custom service

Comment: Thankd for the reply . Can you refer me any example of custom service? I am still unable to change to cusom UUID.

Answer (score 2):

As M. Kotzjan mentioned, I wouldn't modify an existing adopted profile because this can have issues. Instead I would create a new gatt server/peripheral device from scratch. If you want an example to do this from the command line, have a look at the link below:-

- [BlueZ: How to set up a GATT server from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427768/bluez-how-to-set-up-a-gatt-server-from-the-command-line/52982329#52982329)

and if you want code to create a peripheral using the D-Bus API, have a look at the links below:-

- [Creating a BLE Peripheral with BlueZ](https://punchthrough.com/creating-a-ble-peripheral-with-bluez/)
- https://github.com/mhazley/BlueZ-Peripheral